# Count or Find Unique Values for a specific key

Tags: powershell

I feel like this shouldn't be that hard, but I'm having trouble getting a data structure in mind that will give me what I want. I have a large amount of data and I need to find the instances where there are multiple `Secondary Identifiers` as defined below.

```
Primary Identifier,Secondary Identifier,Fruit
11111,1,apple
11111,1,pear
22222,1,banana
22222,1,grapefruit
33333,1,apple
33333,1,pear
33333,2,apple
33333,2,orange
```

That might not be a great example to use - but basically only two of the columns matter. What I'd really like is to return the `Primary Identifiers` where the unique count of `Secondary Identifiers` is greater than 1. So I'm thinking maybe a `HashTable` would be my best bet, but I tried to doing something in a pipeline oriented way and failed so I'm wondering if there is an easier method or `Cmdlet` that I haven't tried.

The final `array` (or `hashtable`) would be something like this:

```
ID      Count of Secondary ID
-----   ---------------------
11111   1
22222   1
33333   2
```

At that point, getting the instances of multiple would be as easy as `$array | Where-Object {$_."Count of Secondary ID" -gt 1}`

If this example sucks or what I'm after doesn't make sense, let me know and I can rewrite it; but it's almost like I need an implementation of `Select-Object -Unique` that would allow you to use two or more input objects/columns. Basically the same as `Excel`'s remove duplicates and then selecting which headers to include. Except there are too many rows to open in `Excel`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Group-Object` twice - first to group the objects by common `Primary Identifier`, then use `Group-Object` again to count the number of distinct `Secondary Identifier`'s within each group:

```sh
$data = @'
Primary Identifier,Secondary Identifier,Fruit
11111,1,apple
11111,1,pear
22222,1,banana
22222,1,grapefruit
33333,1,apple
33333,1,pear
33333,2,apple
33333,2,orange
'@ |ConvertFrom-Csv 

$data |Group-Object 'Primary Identifier' |ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject]@{
    # Primary Identifier value will be the name of the group, since that's what we grouped by
    'Primary Identifier' = $_.Name
    # Use `Group-Object -NoElement` to count unique values - you could also use `Sort-Object -Unique`
    'Count of distinct Secondary Identifiers' = @($_.Group |Group-Object 'Secondary Identifier' -NoElement).Count
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! `Group-Object` is what I was missing in life. The only thing I can't figure out is why you need to wrap the value of `Count of distinct Secondary Identifiers` in an array. It works great, and doesn't work without `@()` - but `($_.Group | Group-Object 'Secondary' -NoElement).Count` is returning a single value right? How does the `@` get what we want?

Comment: The output objects from `Group-Object` _also_ have a `Count` property, which you'll then get in place of the total count of distinct groups if the `@()` is not in place and only one item exists in the group

Comment: Hmmm - I'm still missing something in my mind, but I do see where the issue is with only one item in the group. What exactly is `@()` doing? Forcing an array of arrays like I was thinking? I see that `'Count of distinct Secondary Identifiers' = (($_.Group |Group-Object 'Secondary Identifier' -NoElement).Values).Count` works, so I take it that the `.Count` we're using for distinct groups is a `pwsh` count, but I'm still not sure I understand why a one item `GroupInfoNoElement` object has a `.Count` of 2 instead of 1

Comment: Nice. What _should_ be the most straightforward way to get distinct elements from a(n unsorted) collection is `Select-Object -Unique`, which, unfortunately, has severe performance problems as of PowerShell 7.2 - see [GitHub issue #11221](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11221).

Comment: @immobile2, consider the difference between `(@{ Count = 10 }).Count` and `(@{ Count = 10 }, @{ Count = 20 }).Count`. Using `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) ensures that even a single object is treated as an array.